# Function to get image from media library

Tags: media-library

Is it possible to retreive media image directly into the library... Something like get_media ('all') and it return a array with image url, caption, description etc etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
function get_media_all_wpa14177(){
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type' =>'image',
        'post_status' => 'inherit',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );
    $query_images = new WP_Query( $args );
    $images = array();
    foreach ( $query_images->posts as $image) {
        $images[]= $image->guid;
    }
    return $images;
}
```

### Usage:

```
$Images = get_media_all_wpa14177();
```

Comment: The `guid` is not guaranteed to always point to an existing file, it's better to return the attachment post IDs and then use the specific functions, like [`wp_get_attachment_metadata`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_metadata).